macOS 'open -a' command will only pass arguments to the app if -n option is passed
I was following a tutorial on how to open a Jetbrains IDE from command line, the command being:
open -na {app_name} --args --line {line_number} {file_path} 

So this command works well, but from both the tutorial and open --help I see that the -n option means

Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.

This is not what I want. In that specific case it's not a big deal as it looks like only once instance of a Jetbrains IDE can exist, so it will try to open a new instance and redirect to the running one (I can see a new icon bouncing in the dock then it switches to the existing one).
However, if I don't pass the -n option, it will open the already running app but it looks like the arguments are ignored. (I know I can still pass the file path with open -na {app_name} {file_path}, but I need the line number focus). Unless the app is not running yet, in which case it's the exact same as -na.
At first I thought it was an issue with Jetbrains, but I tried other apps (like Google Chrome and Safari) and it seems it comes from the open command itself.
Is it a bug or is this expected? The description of the -n option says nothing about the arguments. Is it because the apps read the arguments only if a new instance is launched?

It is expected behavior, as --args are passed to the app during launch.
You can quit the app first with:
osascript -e 'tell application "appname" to if it is running then quit'

Then open -a the app with --args, without -n

So this means I cannot write a command that opens an IDE and focus on a line number without trying to open a new instance first?

You can write a command... but open is not going to pass --args to an already running instance.  It's just going to make the app the active app if its already running.  If you need to tell the already running app to do something, you might use an applescript.

A question on osascript, can you simply run osascript -e 'tell application "appname" to quit'

@Philippe you could but then you may end up sending applescript to a non running app.  Even more simply you could also state osascript -e 'quit app "appname"' but old habits (test if running first) die hard.
